# Inverse homomorphism of (00+1)*

Tags: automata, finite-automata, automata-theory

I found an example of inverse homomorphism of regular expression (00+1)* (on page no 131 of 'Hopcroft, Motwani, ullman' book).

If h(a)=01 and h(b)=10 then auther says that inverse homomorphism of the given regular expression is regular expression (ba)*.

But there are strings 00 and 1 in the language of (00+1)* which cannot be represented by any string in language of (ba)*.

Is this example wrong or Am I thinking in wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not strings in the language (ba)* that represent strings in (00+1)* but the other way round. The homomorpisam maps from the alphabet of (ba)* to strings over the alphabet of (00+1)*. Therefore the INVERSE homomorphism maps the other way round.

The image contains all strings that have a picture in (00+1)* . As you observe correctly, 00 and 1 do not have pictures. Therefore they do not contribute anything. This is how inverse morphisms are different from non-inverse ones. The decisive fact is that all the strings that do contribute, contribute strings from (ba)*.

Comment: Is that, saying h-inverse(01) and h-inverse(10) have some meaning but h-inverse(00) and h-inverse(1) do not?

Comment: Similary, h-inverse(0110)=ab, but it is meaningless to say h-inverse(1100)?

Comment: "meaningless" is maybe too harsh a word. You could say that those "inputs" do not produce any output. It is similar to a mapping not being defined for the given input, but not quite the same.